# How to make this function do this in an interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, module, innerhtml, charat

I'm trying to get the first function, to run repeatedly. Like it does in the second function. Where should I take a look?

```
     (function printLetterByLetter() {
    var i = 0;
    var destination = "comment";
    var RandomComment = [
    "Did you choose that outfit?"
    , "I like trains."];
    var message = RandomComment[Math.floor(Math.random() * RandomComment.length)];
    var typewriter = function () {
        document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
        i++;
        if (i > message.length) {
            clearInterval(typespeed);
        }
    }
    var speed = 60;
    var typespeed = setInterval(typewriter, speed)
}());



(function printLetterByLetter() {
     var destination = "comment";
     var frequency = 1000;
     var RandomComment = [
        "Did you choose that outfit?"
        , "I like trains."];
     var RandomCommentTimer = setInterval(function () {
        var message = RandomComment[Math.floor(Math.random() * RandomComment.length)];

    }, frequency)
}());
```

So what i'm trying to do is to make **one** function/module that types out a random comment at a set speed(**first function**). And after a set time the comment will disappear and a new comment will be typed out(**second function**). And like the second function this will go on.
So far I haven't made it work myself so I thought: let's see if anyone can help me on stackoverflow.

If anyone can give a tip on where to take a look, that is also most welcome.

Comment: Not certain what Question is?

Comment: your second IIFE is unusual in that the arguments (destination etc) will be undefined (as you don't assign any value to them in the invocation) and you declare vars of the same name inside the body of the IIFE. Secondly, they both output to `#comment` - so, how do you think running them both (either as separate "functions" or a single one) would work?

Comment: The two functions are essentially the same, the only difference is the messages in the `RandomComment` arrays. How do you want to combine them?

Comment: There were more comments, I pulled some out of the array so the post would be shorter. 
What I want to have eventually is one function that does both of the things that these two functions now do separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could set and alter the function parameters outside of the function then access them inside. Caveat is that you can't put `var` in front when setting them. Not putting var in front makes it accessible outside of the current scope.

```
destination = "comment";
frequency = 6000;
(function printLetterByLetter() {
//now you have access to destination and frequency as they are defined before the function is called
var RandomComment = [
"Did you choose that outfit?"
, "I like trains."];
var RandomCommentTimer = setInterval(function () {
    var message = RandomComment[Math.floor(Math.random() * RandomComment.length)];
    document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML = message;
}, frequency)
}());
```

Comment: Yes oke thank you, this does look better. But this is not the part where I'm stuck.